# for loop vectors of vector in julia

Tags: julia, nested-for-loop

- *first question*

Suppose

```
b=[  [1,[2,3,4]], [4,[-2,1,0]]  ]

for i in 1:length(b)
   for a in b[i][2]
     print(a)
   end
end
```

I am getting `2 3 4 -2 1 0`

instead of  `[2,3,4] ; [-2,1,0]`

- *Second question*

Why the following code  is giving error
`[a for a in b[i][2] for i in 1:length(b)]`

> UndefVarError: i not defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first question,

```
b=[  [1,[2,3,4]], [4,[-2,1,0]]  ]

for i in 1:length(b)
   for a in b[i][2]
     print(a)
   end
end
```

you are iterating over `b[i][2]` in the inner loop, so you get elements from `[2,3,4]` and `[-2,1,0]` as expected. You should `println(b[i][2])`, instead, and remove inner loop.

A better loop would be:

```
for (i,j) in b
    println(j)
end
```

For the second question,

```
[a for a in b[i][2] for i in 1:length(b)]
```

The order of the loops is reversed because the `a` loop depends on the `i` loop. You can fix it in either of two ways,

```
[a for i in 1:length(b) for a in b[i][2]]
# OR
[[a for a in b[i][2]] for i in 1:length(b)]
```

If you want the same answer as the first question but using array comprehension, this will do it:

```
[j for (i,j) in b]
```